# Handling different inputs in chart in the frontend

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a dashboard where I show the vital signs received from the smart watches. There are a lot of smart watches and I need to handle them all in the front-end. I change the IDs of the page elements based on the person who selects the dashboard, so that I have the information of all the smartwatches at the same time in several tabs (I don't know if this is correct or not!).
In one of the elements related to blood pressure, I use the area chart of [JSCharting](https://jscharting.com/).
In this chart, in order to change its values, I change it as follows through the name of chart.

```
bpChart = JSC.chart('bpChart', { 
      // padding: 0,
      debug: true, 
      type: 'area spline',
      title: {
        label: {
          text: titleText,
        }, ...
}
bpChart.series(0).points.add({ y: element.high[1], x: element.high[0] }, { shift: true })
```

The problem is that in this case I have to put a lot of charts in the Javascript code, which is not logical. I want to have one chart and when I open 4 tabs from this dashboard, the information of each smart watch will go to its own chart.
Does anyone have any ideas to recommend?